# Why the result of embedded field with Djongo is empty set

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

**This is My Code**

```
from djongo import models


class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Entry(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog,

    )
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self._id.__str__()
```

**This is My Query**

```
from generator.models import *
e =Entry()
e.headline='h1'
e.blog={'name':'n1','tagline':"t1"}
e.save()
res = Entry.objects.all()
#res[0].blog
#{'name': 'n1', 'tagline': 't1'}
res = Entry.objects.filter(blog__startswith={'name':'n'})
#res
#<QuerySet []>
```

Is the query  right
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpRRL.jpg)

The result of embedded field with Djongo query would not be empty

Comment: It looks like this was an issue with earlier versions of djongo - see https://github.com/doableware/djongo/pull/592 . Are you using the latest version?